# flutter http get function to azure http trigger

Tags: flutter, azure, http, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

Currently using flutter as my webapp to view data from azure for that, I'm using http trigger function to send data after a request from flutter web app. I created a http trigger in azure and used the function URL to connect with http trigger function. But when I run the below code,

```
  Future<void> main() async {
  // Construct the URL to fetch data from Azure function
  String url = "https://dashboardfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger?code=*************==";

  try {
    // Make the HTTP GET request
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url)
      // headers: {
      //   'Authorization': Key,
      //   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // },
    );

    // Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Parse the response body (data from Azure IoT Hub)
      String responseBody = response.body;
      print('Data from Azure IoT Hub: $responseBody');
      // Process the data as needed
      // Example: Convert JSON data to Dart objects
    } else {
      // If the request was not successful, print the error
      print('Failed to fetch data from Azure IoT Hub. Error code: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Catch any exceptions that occur during the HTTP request
    print('Error fetching data from Azure IoT Hub: $error');
  }
}
```

I get this error. What would be the issue.

> Error fetching data from Azure IoT Hub: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=https://nodereddashboardfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger?code=************==

Comment: CORS issue maybe,  please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65086865/2179571

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @chunhunghan, You need to implement a backend layer that calls this API and also configure CORS setting in your Azure Function App to allow calling the Web app or localhost to communicate with it:-

You can make use of the code below:-

***Project/lib/main.dart:-***

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Azure Function Data Fetcher',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? data;

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    String url = "https://siliconfun39.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?code=Bb_G8tbaTi-dUpdGVt94rY13xCDxOZoctmwXejDojbHwAzFu6bVr3A==";

    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          data = response.body;
        });
      } else {
        print('Failed to fetch data. Error code: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error fetching data: $error');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Azure Function Data Fetcher'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: fetchData,
              child: Text('Fetch Data from Azure Function'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            if (data != null)
              Text(
                'Data from Azure Function: $data',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the Function App CORS add the Web App url which has your Flutter app deployed also add the localhost url if you are running your Flutter App locally:-

[image]

If the error persists, Create a proxy to request this Function Url from your Flutter app.